# Greenhills programming target through command line only

Tags: arm, greenhills

Hi I was wondering if greenhills provided any kind of utility to allow for downloading a .elf to a target through a ghs probe through the command line only.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific, but given that you are using one of the Green Hills probes, you can use the `mpadmin` utility:

```
mpadmin -update <IP-addr_of_your-probe | -usb> firmware.frm
```